# Current data member minus months on mdx query

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to do a query that calculate the sum of measures in a specified range of time in a period.

```
WITH MEMBER 
    [Measures].[calc] as 
        SUM (
            { [date.time].[day].CurrentMember.LEAD(-30):[date.time].[day].CurrentMember },
            [Measures].[my_value] 
        )
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[calc]} ON COLUMNS,
{[date.time].[day].[2014-07-21 00:00:00.0]:[date.time].[day].[2016-07-21 00:00:00.0]} ON ROWS 
FROM [my_cube]
```

this code works, it return to me the sum of the current member plus the last 30 members before it,but I'm looking for a way to subtract instead members(days in this case), months, because not all months have 30 days, there's some way to do this? because if there isn't, for each day of my interval will be needed to do one request to do what I want in my java code

Comment: Do you want to get the current month value instead of 30 days?

Comment: I want to get the current month of the current member and subtract months instead of a number of days, in that part that I made a sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you you have a hierarchy with day-month relation (say, calendar), you can use the day's parent:

```
WITH MEMBER 
    [Measures].[calc] as 
        SUM (
            { [date.time].[calendar].CurrentMember.LEAD(-30):[date.time].[calendar].CurrentMember },
            ([date.time].[calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Lag(1),[Measures].[my_value]) 
        )
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[calc]} ON COLUMNS,
{[date.time].[day].[2014-07-21 00:00:00.0]:[date.time].[day].[2016-07-21 00:00:00.0]} ON ROWS 
FROM [my_cube]
```

If you don't have the hierarchy, you can use the day key to regenerate it into the month key:

```
WITH MEMBER 
    [Measures].[calc] as 
        SUM (
            { [date.time].[day].CurrentMember.LEAD(-30):[date.time].[day].CurrentMember },
            (StrToMember('[date.time].[month].[' + left([date.time].[day].CurrentMember.Properties('Key'),7) + ']').Lag(1),[Measures].[my_value]) 
        )
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[calc]} ON COLUMNS,
{[date.time].[day].[2014-07-21 00:00:00.0]:[date.time].[day].[2016-07-21 00:00:00.0]} ON ROWS 
FROM [my_cube]
```